# How to find the maximal 2-norm $\|x\|$ when the point $x$ in a Polyhedron?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{q\times n}$, $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $b \in\mathbb{R} ^{q}$.
The set $H=\{x:Ax\leq b\}$ is a Polyhedral set. I got to determine the maximum
$$S_{max}=\max\{x^Tx:Ax\leq b\}$$
Maybe I can rewrite the problem as $$L_{max}=\max\{x^Tx+\sum_i\lambda_i(A_ix-b_i)\}$$ by Langrangian approach. The maximum is caused by KKT conditions, i.e. $\frac{dL_{max}}{dx}=0$ with $\lambda_i\ge0$, $\lambda_i(A_ix-b_i)=0$ and $A_ix-b_i\le0$ for $i=1,2,\cdots,q$. Here, $A_i$ is the $i^{th}$ row of $A$ and $b_i$ is the $i^{th}$ ingredient of $b$.
$\frac{dL_{max}}{dx}=2x^T+\sum_i\lambda_iA_i=0$ implies $x=-\frac{1}{2}\sum_i\lambda_iA_i^T$.
The maximum $x=-\frac{1}{2}\sum_i\lambda_iA_i^T$ is irrelevant to $b$. Is it wrong? I guess the maximum is obtained when $x$ is the some vertex of $H$.

Comment: In general a polyhedron has no circumscribed sphere...

Comment: I also wonder if the maximum is obtained when x is the some vertex of H.

Comment: I see you have modified your text: so you mean the/ radius of a sphere (or "the" sphere) centered in the origin containing the polyhedron **with minimal radius**. Could you confirm this is the idea ?

Comment: Maybe I haven't understood your question, but why don't you plainly compute the **extremal points** $x_k$ of your polyhedron and then take the max of the $x_k^Tx^k$ ?

Comment: Yes, this is the idea. I have realized that  the maximal  $x_k^Tx_k$ is obtained in the extremal points $x_k$ of my polyhedron. In the beginning, I consider it by constraints$Ax<=b$, which is not good for analysis. Thanks very much.